# How to run ccminer 1.2 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, bumblebee, bitcoin

I'm having trouble running `ccminer` 1.2 on my Lenovo IdeaPad-Z500 with a NVIDIA GT 740M which is a CUDA capable GPU according to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. I installed the CUDA toolkit following http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html (added the repository and updated the repos and installed `cuda`). Starting `ccminer` causes error

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device
[2014-12-26 03:26:50] Unable to query number of CUDA devices! Is an nVidia driver installed?
```

Invokation with `optirun`, i.e. `optirun ccminer`, alone and in combination with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo optirun ccminer` and `optirun sudo ccminer` causes

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found.
[2014-12-26 03:29:08] Unable to query number of CUDA devices! Is an nVidia driver installed?
```

Adding an alias to `/etc/modprobe.conf` in the form

```
alias nvidia nvidia-340
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia-340-uvm
```

doesn't change a thing. `nvidia-340`, `nvidia-340-uvm` (340.36) and `bumblebee` (3.2.1-5+xedgers14.10.1) are installed. `optirun -vv bash` gives output

```
[37049.350238] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[37049.350909] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[37049.350962] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[37049.350981] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[37049.350999] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[37049.351015] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-340:/usr/lib32/nvidia-340
[37049.351032] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[37049.351049] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[37049.351066] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[37049.351082] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[37049.351098] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[37049.351308] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[37051.419635] [INFO]Response: Yes. X is active.

[37051.419696] [INFO]Running application using primus.
[37051.419905] [DEBUG]Process bash started, PID 21812.
```

`sudo modprobe -v nvidia-340-uvm` causes error

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.1-031801-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_340_uvm': No such device
```

which I don't understand. I added the xorg-edgers PPA `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`.

Currently the usage is unclear for me because there's no `--help` argument (requested as https://github.com/cbuchner1/ccminer/issues/29), but it might be retrievable from somewhere.

After installation of the CUDA examples with `/usr/local/cuda/bin/cuda-install-samples-6.5.sh ~/cuda-examples/` I ran the `deviceQuery` binary which fails with

```
bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

and `optirun deviceQuery` which fails with

```
bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found.
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

Comment: Use a different bitcoin mining software.

Comment: @ThomasW. Can you image that your comment in the current form is not as useful as it might be in another? It's not even a comment in the SE sense, but a (highly extensible) answer.

Comment: Well, all I can say is try a different mining software.  Hardware and/or software specific problems such as this one where it isn't detected by the miner are pretty infinitely broad and impossible to answer.  I also don't support GPU mining except for fun and as a method to literally burn your computer - as GPU mining died a long time ago

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry, I read your comment as a non-constructive opinion-(that there's a better mining software to be used instead)based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the CUDA toolkit installation instructions and figuring out some compilation issues of the CUDA toolkit examples (following solution applies to them as well), I found out that

1. `cudaminer` 746a7733dda9d2b3466c54c149362e4fb205cc3f works when invoked with `optirun env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 LANG=C ./cudaminer` with `-o` and `-O` option in source root after compilation with `optirun env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 LANG=C make`
2. 1 shows that compilation (with the same parameters and commands) of `ccminer` 1.2 fails because the `CC`, `GCC` and `CXX` variables seem to be ignored

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and just got ccminer working by using auto Nvidia symbolic link with `update-alternatives`. Try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

choose auto (0) and enter